# Django NEWBIE - TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

(My project directory is called **test** and the app in question is called **posts**)

**Django tried loading these templates, in this order:**

Using engine django:

```
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /path-to-app-dir/virtual/test/posts/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /path-to-app-dir/virtual/platform/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /path-to-app-dir/virtual/platform/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
     return render(request,'templates/index.html')
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('', views.index)
]
```

I have mentioned the app in Settings.py so that probably shouldn't be an issue.

What am I doing wrong ?

[filetree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaQXe.png)

Comment: Can you share your filetree with the template in it?

Comment: I have just edited the post and added the filetree at the bottom

Comment: can you include the filetree as text, with most Linux distributions, you can use `tree` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template is placed under `posts/templates/posts/`. If you enable the `APP_DIRS`, then it will look for all `templates/` directories in all apps, but it is still placed under a `posts/` directory, hence you access the template with:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
     return render(request,'posts/index.html')
```

Comment: the APP_DIRS is set to True,
and I did try it as you said, but still the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the template directories in `settings.py`.

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "templates"], # BASE_DIR / Your-templates-folder
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Since you have `index.html` is under the `posts` folder, the template path in `views.py` should be `templates/posts/index.html`

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
     return render(request, 'templates/posts/index.html')
```

Comment: i thought APP_DIRS searched for and located the templates directory? 
do I still need to add the path to it on the "DIRS": ?